# add html to a file

Tags: javascript, html, include

I am currently busy with a website and need your help.

What I want to have is a piece of javascript that enables me to add actual code my html file. sort of an extension. 
On my website I have a couple of music video, but I don't want any spoilers so I want to hide the last music video. So basicly you have to watch the first three and then press on a button to watch the fourth without leaving your website.

so:

Watch video 1, 2 and 3. press on a button. *plop* a fourth video shows up as an extension of your html page and you can watch that.

so in code it would be something like:

```
<script> function fourthVideo() { 
    [the javascript ] 
}
</script>

...

<div>
  [ youtube video #1 ]
  [ youtube video #2 ]
  [ youtube video #3 ]
</div>

<input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="fourthVideo()">

<div>
  [ youtube video #4 ] //this would be added by the javascript
</div>
```

and then the javascript adds the div with the fourth video at the bottom of the page.

I tried to explain it as good as I can (quite tired... ) so, if it's still unclear please say so and i'll try to explain better once i've had some sleep, heh.

cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to "add" a whole new div, you can just show and hide it using css.

```
<div id="videoFour" style="display:none;"> 
  Video.. 
</div>

function fourthVideo() {
  document.getElementById("videoFour").setAttribute("style", "display: block");
}
```